# oleDB inserting new entry

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb

I am created database using microsoft access. From this database i can only read the data and can't add new entries to it,

I use below code to insert data

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into [Accountstbl] values(" + textBox1.Text + 
",' " + textBox6.Text + " ',' " + textBox3.Text + " ')", cn);
```

But when I click ok, the form just turns to not responding and didn't insert any data in the database, I know my path is correct because I can read the data,

can you give me a guide about this? can't find anything :(
thanks,

Comment: Try working with parameters and did you execute cmd.ExecuteNonQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing single quote for first textbox(textBox1.Text)?

Try Below one

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into [Accountstbl] values('" + textBox1.Text + 
"',' " + textBox6.Text + " ',' " + textBox3.Text + " ')", cn);
```

And try to put the below code where you have a doubt that its going wrong

```
try
{
   //Insertion code here, .............Query,ExcuteNonQuery,.....etc
} 
catch(Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());//You will get here what problem is there.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into [Accountstbl] (field1, field2, field3) values(" + textBox1.Text + ",' " + textBox6.Text + " ',' " + textBox3.Text + " ')", cn);
```

Replace field# with the ones in your database.